# How can I print multiple values in one line by `jq`?

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have json data like below:

```json
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "id": {
                "S": "c921e4eb-5958-424a-ae3a-b9cada0d9481"
            },
            "type": {
                "S": "transaction.1612878877726"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "S": "355057f0-4327-49c7-979f-5a27410d81ba"
            },
            "type": {
                "S": "transaction.1612345630260"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "S": "664dc02f-0ad8-484a-98a5-a403beea775b"
            },
            "type": {
                "S": "transaction.1612164919232"
            }
        },
...
  ]
}
```

I'd like to print the value `id` and `type` in one line per item from the `Items` array, e.g.

```
c921e4eb-5958-424a-ae3a-b9cada0d9481, transaction.1612878877726
355057f0-4327-49c7-979f-5a27410d81ba, transaction.1612345630260
...
```

I tried `cat file | jq  '.Items[].id.S, .Items[].type.S'` but it prints `id` and `type` in separate lines. How can I achieve it with jq?

Answer (score 6):

I would just use string manipulation, either adding 3 strings :

```
jq --raw-output '.Items[] | .id.S + ", " + .type.S' file
```

or using string interpolation :

```
jq --raw-output '.Items[] | "\(.id.S), \(.type.S)"' file
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/NHzb0MJ1tH).